# radius of convergence of a function defined in terms of another function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose g is a continuous function on $[0, 2]$ and suppose $t→1$

Have that $g(t) = 2$

Determine the
interval of convergence for the power series
$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(1+1/n)x^n$

**My attempt:**
Ratio test implies that $x$ should be between $(-1,1)$. I am trying to determine endpoint behavior. How do I proceed?

Facts I have: G is continuous on a compact set, so it achieves its maxima and minima on the set. Maybe I can use this to bound the terms and use a comparison test?

Comment: What happens to the absolute value of the terms if $|x|=1$?

Comment: So, $\lim_{t \to 1} g(t)= 2$, is that correct?

Comment: @OlivierRoche Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Set $c_n := g(1+\frac{1}{n})$, so that $F(x) = \sum c_n x^n$.

Your radius of convergence is $1$. 
Indeed, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{|c_n|} = 1 $ :

Let $M := \sup_{[0;2]}|g|$. For all $n$, we have $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{|c_n|}\leqslant \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{M}$.
On the other hand, there's $N>0$ such that $n>N \Rightarrow c_n>\frac{1}{2}$, hence, for $n>N$, we have $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{|c_n|}\geqslant \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{\frac{1}{2}}$ . The claims follows from :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{\frac{1}{2}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{M} = 1$$

Comment: Oh, this I have determined. My question was about the endpoint behavior of the series. Since $g(1 + 1/n)$ does not go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, we have divergence at $x=1$. Similarly, I have the lemma that if $a_n$ goes to zero, then so does $|a_n|$. And I can then say that at $x= -1$, we have divergence again. Does this make sense?

Comment: @childishsadbino Yes it makes sense.Call $R$ the radius of convergence (here $R=1$). Your series will converge whenever $|x|<R$, diverge whenever $|x|>R$, but the behaviour of the series for each $x$ such that $|x|=R$ depends on the series at hand. For your series, the series diverges for all  $x$ such that $|x|=R$ (namely $1$ and $-1$)..